# How to batch edit a list of files?

Tags: linux, unix-shell, batch-processing

I have a list of files where I need to remove some lines that have been added yesterday by a spambot. The section I want to remove looks like this:

```
^M
<script>[...] bunch of malware code [...]</script>
```

That section seems to have been appended to the files, so I can be relatively sure it's the last lines of each file that contain this part.

Now I know a bit of Linux, but not enough to do this via a command. How would I go about and do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the malware code consistent?  does it start and end with the same text in all cases??

If you can write a regexp, you can do something like:

```
perl -npi.bak -e 's/startofcode.*?endofcode//' file1 file2 file3 orglob*
```

Comment: or sed if perl is not available on the machine (unusual but could happen)